# How to make newline (\n,\break,\\ ...) in octave plot (figure) when printing (saving)?

Tags: plot, save, newline, octave, fltk

Task is simple. I would like to make this legend work:

```
h = legend ('measured', 'linear fit R(0)$\break$ = 2$\Omega$$\mu$m');
```

Special characters are working, but not a new line. Simple '\n' is working with qt. However, qt doesn't know greek symbols ... . Gnuplot doesn't recognise lot of  linewidth settings and uses ugly font for symbols.
So I ended up with `graphics_toolkit fltk`. And for save I use:

```
print -depslatexstandalone test_epslatex
system("latexmk test_epslatex.tex -ps");
system("latexmk -c");
```

However, I'm not able to tell latex that I want a new line. It would look much better.

Update:

Using `graphics_toolkit fltk`, and this legend configuration:

```
h = legend ('measured', cstrcat('linear fit',"\n",'R(0) = ',num2str(p(2),5),'$\Omega$'));
```

it looks like this in the window:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2R3d.png)

And after saving (XLSfile is string with name of input XLSfile):

```
% saving to png and ps
pom = XLSfile;
pom = strrep(pom, '.xls', '_Rdist');
print(pom,'-depslatexstandalone');

system(cstrcat('latexmk ',pom,'.tex -ps'));
system("latexmk -c");

pom1 = 'gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m ';
pom2 = '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r800s600 -sOutputFile=';
pom3 = cstrcat(pom,'.png ',pom ,'.ps');
system(cstrcat(pom1,pom2,pom3));

% remove unwanted:
system(cstrcat('rm ',pom,'.dvi ',pom,'.tex ',pom,'-inc.eps'));
```

It looks like this: [saved png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAjb7.png)

I realized few things: "\noTexWorksHere", 'no new line character works here\n'. So combination of them should work ...

The dollar signs have to be there since export is using Latex no Tex.
Also there is an issue with legend :( . And It is wrong in the first export to eps from print command. In export, Octave is drawing legend background directly after graph background. That's why the grid is on the legend. I should fill the bug report but don't know how yet (I installed octave few days ago).

Some technical details: Ubuntu 16.04, Octave 4.0.0, hopefully well configured latex (it's working, but I'm a bit new user)

Comment: Please try to create complete examples which can be copy&pasted from someone who tries to help you. And I can't see from your question, how the result should look. Perhaps you can sketch the result by hand or draw an image?

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the interest, hope additional info will help. I can send you whole code, but I thing it's not necessary. Do you thing I should use octave mailing list?